# angular2 add dynamic fields that comes from collection value using formBuilder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I want to add dynamic input field in form using formBuilder (input comes from database ). eg. In collection i saved multiple fields and i want to create from based on that fields that i saved in collection (LIKE::-

```
      Collections Name: Custome_fields
      In above collection in save below fields
      Age
      Name
      Height
```

And now i want to create input in form using above fields name:
For this i am using below that:

```
<div [formGroup]="studentCustomeField" *ngFor="let customField of customFields;" class="col-md-8">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="" id="Label_padding">{{customField.label | titlecase }}</label>
    <input formControlName="customField.label" [(ngModel)]="student.customFields" type="text" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="{{ customField.label | uppercase }}">
</div>
```

```
Below is code in my component.ts file:


this.companyService.getCustomFields()
        .then(customFieldsData => {
            if(customFieldsData) {
                this.customFields = customFieldsData;
                console.log('Testing: '+JSON.stringify(this.customFields));

                this.studentCustomeField = this.formBuilder.group({
                    customFields.label: [''],
                })  
            } else {
                console.log('component else');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact structure, of your CustomFields object, but assuming it is something like:

```
const CustomFields = {
  Age: 12,
  Height: 13,
  Name: "Antonio"
}
```

You can use the following code to generate the form group:

```
const formGroup = Object.keys(customFields).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = [customFields[curr], Validators.required];

  return acc;
}, {});
```

And you will get the following object as `formGroup`

```
// {
//   Age: [12, Validators.required],
//   Height: [13, Validators.required],
//   Name: ['Antonio', Validators.required],
// };

this.studentCustomeField = this.formBuilder.group(formGroup);
```

Comment: thanks,
Now, what i write in HTML side i mean in input type: i am using below but it throwing error:

    <input formControlName="acc[curr]" type="text" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="{{ customField.label | uppercase }}">

Comment: Can you provide the exact structure of your customFieldsData object ?

Comment: Hello Alexandru, Please Review my code https://jsfiddle.net/w7290tv2/  in this link.

Comment: did you got any idea ?

Comment: I need you to run, console.log(customFieldsData) for me to see the exact structure of your fields